# write "isTriangular" function, which takes a positive integer and returns 1 if the given number is a triangular number; returns 0, otherwise

Tags: c

Write isTriangular function, which takes a positive integer and returns 1 if the given number is a triangular number; returns 0, otherwise.

The  main function is okay, but there is some errors in "isTriangular" function which i can not see, please help me.Triangular numbers are shown below:

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isTriangular(int N)
{
    int sum = 0, n = 0;
    for (n; sum <= N; n++)
        sum += n;

    if (sum == N)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;    
}


int main()
{
    int x;
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x > 0)
        {
            if (isTriangular(x))
                printf("%d is a triangular number\n", x);
            else
                printf("%d is NOT a triangular number\n", x);
        }
    }
    while (x > 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort and no clear question.

Comment: Where is your code? We need to see `isTriangular` (and the errors you are getting).

Comment: there is an error i can not add my code

Comment: Why can't you add your code? How should we be able to help you without code? We can't guess the error.

Comment: i am trying to add it

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: ok, sorry for this

Comment: `but there is some errors ` Please be more specific.

Comment: the answer is always "NOT a triangular number" even if i give a triangular number such as for example 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change termination condition from `sum <= N` to `sum < N`.

Comment: yes, now it works, but could you explain please what is the difference?

Comment: You loop run for 1 extra time which make sum greater than N. So even in valid case sum never equals to N. Hence fails.